# mod_rewrite rules fail after apache restart

Tags: apache, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I have the following rewrite rules but every time I restart Apache they prevent apache from restarting and FAIL.

One error was...

> `Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 82 of /var/www/vhosts/current_release/url-rewrite-maps/catchall.txt: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression
>   '^/ProductDetails\.aspx\?PromotionID\(.*)\&id\(.*)$' [FAILED]`

```
RewriteRule ^/ProductSearch\.aspx\?Ntt\=(.*)\&N\=(.*)$ catalogsearch/result/?q=$2 [R=302,L,NC]  
#old search redirect to search

RewriteRule ^/ProductSearch\.aspx\?viewall\=1\&N\=(.*)$ productsearch.aspx?N=$1 [R=302,NC]  
#viewall with N parameter to another redirect rule for URL with N= value only

RewriteRule ^/ProductSearch\.aspx\?(Ne|No)\=(.*)\&N\=(.*)$ productsearch.aspx?N=$3 [R=302,NC]  
#url with Ne OR No param and N= to productsearch.aspx redirect on URLs with N= only

RewriteRule ^/ProductDetails\.aspx\?PromotionID\=(.*)\&id\=(.*)$ productdetails.aspx?id=$2 [R=302,NC]  
#should pass the PID into the ID= and redirect from there

RewriteRule ^/ProductDetails\.aspx\?id\=(.*)\&RSSLINK\=(.*) productdetails.aspx?id=$1 [R=302, NC]
```

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because what you are trying to do is invalid.  You can't access the query string through the regexp match pattern -- its not allowed.  You have to use a rewrite condition to pick up the query string, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}          PromotionID=(.*?)&id=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/ProductDetails\.aspx$  productdetails.aspx?id=%2 [R=302,NC,L]
```

You can create a ladder of these and put a catchall at the bottom

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}   ^$
RewriteRule ^                        /catchall.txt [L]
```

This will do an internal redirect of any request that wasn't matched by the previous rules to your catch all.  The condition is there to stop an infinite redirection loop.

Comment: I have a series of pointers to different rewrite map files, each has a condition and two rules, and at the end of those specific examples there's an include to a catchall.txt. So, can you use a RewriteCond in an included file like this? (going to try anyway...)

Comment: I ended up having to put the rewrite conditions in the apache .conf, not in my separate catchall file. I ended up not using the catchall after all the statements like you described, it caused other issues for me.